# How to map several segments of URL to one PathVariable in spring-mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm working on a webapp, one function of which was to list all the files under given path. I tried to map several segments of URL to one PathVariable like this :

```
@RequestMapping("/list/{path}")
public String listFilesUnderPath(@PathVariable String path, Model model) {
     //.... add the file list to the model
     return "list"; //the model name
}
```

It didn't work. When the request url was like `/list/folder_a/folder_aa`, `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` complained : `"Did not find handler method for ..."`

Since the given path could contains any number of segments, it's not practical to write a method for every possible situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In REST each URL is a separate resource, so I don't think you can have a generic solution. I can think of two options

- One option is to change the mapping to `@RequestMapping("/list/**")` (`path` parameter no longer needed) and extract the whole path from request
- Second option is to create several methods, with mappings like `@RequestMapping("/list/{level1}")`, `@RequestMapping("/list/{level1}/{level2}")`, `@RequestMapping("/list/{level1}/{level2}/{level3}")`... concatenate the path in method bodies and call one method that does the job. This, of course, has a downside that you can only support a limited folder depth (you can make a dozen methods with these mappings if it's not too ugly for you)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture zero or more path segments by appending an asterisk to the path pattern.

From the [Spring documentation on `PathPattern`:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html)

> `{*spring}` matches zero or more *path segments* until the end of the path and captures it as a variable named "spring"

Note that the leading slash is part of the captured path as mentioned in the example on the same page:

> `/resources/{*path}` — matches all files underneath the `/resources/`, as well as `/resources`, and captures their relative path in a variable named "path"; `/resources/image.png` will match with "path" → "/image.png", and `/resources/css/spring.css` will match with "path" → "/css/spring.css"

For your particular problem the solution would be:

```java
@RequestMapping("/list/{*path}") // Use *path instead of path
public String listFilesUnderPath(@PathVariable String path, Model model) {
     //.... add the file list to the model
     return "list"; //the model name
}
```